# How to solve the problem 'User memory limit exceeded'?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I'm trying to reduce a region in images of sentinel-1 by calculating the half max-min threshold. I set the scale of grid as 30, and then I came across this problem.

Code link is here:

https://code.earthengine.google.com/d5f28547f0e425f429b7b52a57e4d180

and an extract of it (where values with issues are printed):

```
// Offshore wind farm filter by Half Min-Max theshold
// Reduce the region. The region parameter is the Feature geometry.
var AOI_MaxValue = Sen1VVImg_IntMean.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.max(),
  geometry: grid,
  scale: 30,
  maxPixels: 1e13
});

// Reduce the region. The region parameter is the Feature geometry.
var AOI_MinValue = Sen1VVImg_IntMean.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.min(),
  geometry: grid,
  scale: 30,
  maxPixels: 1e13
});

// Reduce the region. The region parameter is the Feature geometry.
var AOI_MeanValue = Sen1VVImg_IntMean.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  geometry: grid,
  scale: 30,
  maxPixels: 1e13
});

print('AOI_MeanValue', AOI_MeanValue);

//Set the Half min-max threshold
var max1= ee.Number(AOI_MaxValue.getNumber('VV_mean'));
var min1= ee.Number(AOI_MinValue.getNumber('VV_mean'));
var Min_Max = max1.subtract(min1).multiply(0.5);
var OWF_Thershold =  max1.subtract(Min_Max);


print(OWF_Thershold);
```

Can you help me out with this?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed this is a scale issue but there are additional ways to get a computation to run without sacrificing what resolution the computation is done at if you need accurate results and not an approximation.

You can increase the `tileScale` parameter when applying `reduceRegion`. This will allow you to control (to some degree) the number of tiles used for compute so smaller tiles get sent to individual compute nodes reducing the memory footprint. This in turn allows you to keep a higher scale. Also, running multiple reducers is also inefficient and you can group them together in one reduction:

```
var AOI_stats = Sen1VVImg_IntMean.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean().combine({
    reducer2: ee.Reducer.minMax(),
    sharedInputs: true
  }),
  geometry: grid,
  scale: 30,
  tileScale: 16,
  maxPixels: 1e13
});
```

Although this will increase compute time (because of more chunks to process) so long running task may get a computation time out error and if that is the case you can run an export. See documentation on `reduceRegion` for more information: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-image-reduceregion See docs on combining reducers: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/best_practices#combine-reducers